# Insert rows into many-to-many table but avoid FK lookup/subquery

Tags: mysql

I have a many2many table in my DB that gets thousands of pushes every hour. Let's say it looks like:

```
+-----------------------+
| pageNotes             |
+-----+--------+--------+
| id  | pageid | noteid |
+-----+--------+--------+
| 1   | 37583  | 385839 |
| 2   | 37583  | 385840 |
| ... | ...    | ...    |
+-----+--------+--------+
```

When I want to update the table, I only have the page URL (which is in the table "pages", which has pageid as its FK in the pageNotes table).  I really want to avoid having to buffer tens of thousands of records to have the PK lookup in my code so I'm kinda curious wether there's another way - except for subqueries - to achieve this.

Currently, the query looks like:

```
INSERT INTO 
     `pageNotes ` (id,pageid,noteid) 
     VALUES ('',
       (SELECT id FROM pages WHERE url='http://www.test.com/index.html')
       ,385841);
```

This is not usable of course because if the page doesn't exist, the query will fail. What I'm looking for is a way to either fetch the pk OR insert the row in the FK table.

Comment: So, you want to insert a record with a foreign key without obtaining the foreign key? Can you give an example of the query you're using now that you'd like to optimize? That may help us better understand the question.

Comment: Well basically, yes. See the above for the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the query as:

```
INSERT INTO `pageNotes` (id, pageid, noteid)
SELECT '', p.id, 385841
    FROM pages p
    WHERE url = 'http://www.test.com/index.html';
```

Comment: I do have one follow-up question: Can I also specify that if the row isn't found in pages, it should be inserted?

Comment: Doing it that way, if the row isn't found, there will be no insert, so yes.

Comment: Great. Thanks! I'll check wether the row was inserted and otherwise first insert the page and then insert the reference.